# There is a cycle in the hierarchy!" json

Tags: json

I am getting one JSON exception called "net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!"

here is code

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e from employee e ");
List<Employee> employeeList = q.getResultList();
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
response.put("empList", employeeList);
```

here is Employee Entity. it has one to many relation

```
public class Employee {
@Id
private String userId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "T_MENTORS_userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
private Collection<Experience> experience;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the problem? What do you want to do about it?

Answer (score 2):

You may be running into a circular reference. Does `Experience` refer to `Employee` and `Employee` refers to `Experience`?

If so, there is a couple of solutions:

1. Remove the `Employee` reference in `Experience`
2. Create a DTO object: basically it's a new `Employee` object with a property `Experience` that does NOT make a circular reference to
   `Employee`. It'll be ready for serialization. Your
   current classes remain intact.

See Martin Fowler for an overview of DTO:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, according to your business logic, you can delete one of reference, for example :

```
Employee{

      private Collection<Experience> experiences;
}
```

and in Experience

```
Experience
{
 // no reference to Employee
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove the reference from the entity, there is a workaround. 
Use,

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
response.getJsonConfig().
                  setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT)
response.put("empList", employeeList);
```